# Determine order of events happening in discrete timespace

Tags: bayesian, markov-process, discrete-time

At $t=0$ I have a certain (active) population, lets say 1,000 customers. In each time step I expect a certain amount I have a probability of death of 1% and a prepayment rate of 5%. At the end of each time step I need to know how many customers are in which status (active, prepayed or death).

My sample space for each time step would look as follows:

- {Not died, Not prepaid}, $P=(1-1\%)*(1-5\%) = 94.05\%$ (Active)
- {Not died, Prepaid},$P=(1-1\%)*(5\%) = 4.95\%$ (Prepaid)
- {Died, Not Prepaid}, $P=(1\%)*(1-5\%) = 0.95\%$ (Died)
- {Died, Prepaid},$P=(1\%)*(5\%) = 0.05\%$ (Died or prepaid)

For the first 3 statusses it is clear in which status the person ends up. However, when a person both dies and prepays it is important to know which of the two happened first in order to but the person in the correct status bucket.

**How can I determine which of the events happens first such that I can decide what proportion ends up death and prepayed?**

My own thought would be that prepayment is more likely to happen first as this has a higher probability of happening at all (however, as we already know it will happen I am not sure this actually matters). An idea would be to weight using these probabilities:

- {Die first, prepay next}, $P=(1\%)*(5\%)*(1\%/(1\%+5\%)) = 0.0083\%$
- {Prepay first, die next}, $P=(1\%)*(5\%)*(5\%/(1\%+5\%)) = 0.0417\%$

However, I am not really sure whether this actually holds true. Alternatively, I may need to start looking at a continuous distribution for the comparison of the two, but I am actually not sure where / how to start.

Happy to hear your thoughts!

Comment: Can you theoretically *pre*pay after death?

Comment: In this specific case it potentially would be an acceptable simplification to assume this always means death. However, I can think of theoretical possibilities in which this would happen (i.e. due to transaction processing time).
However, I am also looking for a more general answer as I can also think of events that could happen in both orders